# How do you keep a sleep mask on while asleep?

Tags: air-travel, sleeping

I have started wearing a sleep mask on trips as I find it fairly hard getting to sleep in odd places. It works for getting to sleep but almost 100% of the time the mask will no longer be covering my eyes when I wake up. The straps are tight but to no avail.

Occasionally it's still on my head but most of the time it will be in some random place on my lap or nearby. I don't know how it gets off, I assume I take it off unconciously because of the feeling of something weird on my face, but I really have no idea. The result is that I am woken up by the light rather than my alarm.

Has anyone found a way of preventing this issue and keeping the mask on?

Comment: Not closing as cross site duplicate but likely helpfull: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15145/how-to-keep-sleep-mask-on-while-sleeping

Comment: @Willeke it's a shame we can't have cross-site dupes to serve as pointers. That's about as close as dupes ever get, but the question fits here too so deleting doesn't make good sense either. (I knew I recognised it, and was going to flag this one, but you found the old one before me)

Comment: I wonder if you could be unconsciously rubbing at the odd feeling, knocking it off, and it lands in your lap. That would seem more likely than deliberate removal in your sleep, and perhaps easier to deal with, which is why I draw the distinction. Example:  a bit of elastic tied between the straps, passing under your chin, though that seems rather uncomfortable in itself (still better than duct taping it to your head)

Comment: It does seem a life-hacks style question more than one for here. Different brands will surely have different effectiveness - the fabric and presence of any rubber or similar strip would make a lot of difference.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimentation I found a simple solution to this - just do it up tight. I tighten it so that it's not uncomfortable, but conforms to my face pretty closely. This has been the only way I've been able to wake up with it on. Not foolproof but works 90% of the time.